# userdata .backup android

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, restore

My tablet is not rooted. I made a backup of it through console (in recovery mode):

1. boot my tablet in recovery mode
2. go down to menu "backup user data"

After that, in my sdcard, I have three files:

- `userdata_20160211_092627.backup`
- `userdata_20160211_092627.backup1`
- `userdata_20160211_092627.backup2)`

Then I moved the sdcard to another tablet (which is the same model), and recovered this backup there through recovery mode (steps as above, just selecting "restore user data"), but after about 10 seconds I get this error:

"Checksum compare fail".

Does any body know how to fix this error or how to disable the checksum in the .backup file? (this works if i recovered on the same tablet that i have made a backup in)

Thanks

Comment: You can't disable the checksum in the *file*, you would have to alter the restoration code to not care about the checksum.

Comment: @MatthewRead: how to alter the restoration code to not care about the checksum?

Comment: @KhacQuyetDang thanks for your update (I've integrated those facts with your question, so we can remove the now obsolete comments). It's clear now you're using a custom recovery – but not which (and on what device); these details are needed to answer where to disable checksum processing. Most popular custom recoveries are ClockworkMod and TWRP. Which one are you using? What's your device's brand and model?

Comment: My device's brand is DANEW and the model is DSLIDE 1015.  My device is not rooted, so i think the default recovery tool is used.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help you with code issues, as development questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The checksum prevents of stealing data (put sdcard into someones phone and create a backup). You can not restore to even similar phones.

I posted the ektoric solution, please download the script from page 2. This skips checksum and makes it restoreable to other phones. Root is required, but no need to flash custom recovery.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528969&page=2

Comment: A checksum is used to validate the integrity of the data, not to prevent theft.  You're probably thinking of encryption.

Comment: you are technically right. but think twice. you cannot restore to similar phone, even data integrity is intact. why they did so?

Comment: Hi, the link in your post went away. Best would be if you would copy-paste the script here (if it is not too long). If not, then a direct link would be more useful.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/141805